# What's the best way to remove duplicate URI params from a string?

Tags: java, performance

I have a string, `root?param1=...&param2=...&param3=...`, and I want to create a java method that will remove any duplicate params.  The values will always be the same, but sometimes the params are duplicated as per the application's function (don't ask).  Therefor,

```
HTTP://root?param1=value&param2=value2&param2=value2param3=value3&param3=value3&param1=value&param1=value
```

becomes

```
HTTP://root?param1=value&param2=value2&param3=value3
```

I've been out of programming too long to remember the best ways to do this but my original train of thought went something like this:

Grab each param and stick into a temp array, run through temp array and compare if array[i] equals to any other param name.  If so, delete.  If not, add back to a return string.  At end of loop, print return string.

But that would require O(n) for the length of the URI plus O(m)! for the size of the array (m being the number of params).  I think that would be pretty bad considering I'll be running this method around 5,000x per minute for all incoming URIs.  Is there a better way to go about this or an out-of-the-box java method that handles some of the overhead?

Comment: Do you really need to do that? Cannot the recipient of the URL just ignore the duplicate (which is what most implementations already do anyway unless you explicitly look for multi-valued parameters)?

Comment: It's how I want to monitor the list of URLs.  Certain pages have the same action but may have different URLs (varying simply by the number of multiple duplicate params) and I'd rather have one page for a given action than a dozen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stick the key/value pairs into a [`Map<String,String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). That'll automatically take care of duplicated keys, and will be very easy to code up.

To verify that parameters with identical keys have identical values, you could check the return value of [`put()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29): it should be either `null`, or equal to the value you've just inserted.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on doing this (don't?), then you could use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

For each of your parameter - value pairs, insert them into the map.

You'll be left with only unique parameters, which you can then use to rebuild your URI.

You'd be iterating your parameter - value pairs once, then iterating your Map once to rebuild the URI.

Or, like Thilo said, you could not do this and let the receiver deal with the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

For the love of God, don't write your own crufty parser for this.

Find an HTTP library which handles parameter parsing and use that.

This might do the trick: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution with lambda expression in Java.

```
// input: query string
// output: parameter map(Map<String, String>) in least recently updated order 
List<String> pairs = Splitter.on("&").splitToList(queryStr);

return pairs.stream().map(s -> s.split("=", 2)).collect(Collectors.toMap(pair -> pair[0],
                pair -> (pair.length > 1 ? pair[1] : ""), (formerValue, latterValue) -> latterValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```